# Trying To Add TK Text Window to Example, Import tkinter confusion

Tags: python, tkinter

I have been working with several tkinter tutorials including one with Text window and a very helpful tutorial but with out text window. See here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oV68QJJUXTU

I have tried to add a Text window to this example but found the constant END was not defined and the Text window did not open or show up in the frame. I traced it down to a difference in the import. Using "from tkinter import *" the constant END was defined (it was 'end') but using the method of this tutorial, "import tkinter as tk" the constant END was not defined. I defined it to clear the error when I try to use Text window the window never opens (never shows up) in the example so I think either I have to rewrite to use the import * method or I need to understand how to over come the import as tk difference.

It seams that importing as tk is likely to be the more correct method rather than as * so that is the way I think I should be learning to do it.

Any suggestions out there?

This code works

```
from tkinter import *
.....

class set_window(Thread):

    def __init__(self, labelText):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.labelText = labelText
        self.labelText.set("Text Window Display")  

        self.T = Text(root, height=40, width=60, bd=10)
        self.T.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.T.focus_set()
        self.T.insert(END, "Just a text Widget\nin two lines\n")
```

But this did not:

```
    import tkinter as tk

    class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Blast it!", font=XLARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        label_2 = tk.Label(self, text="Input Text Here", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label_2.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        self.T = tk.Text(self, height=40, width=60, bd=10)        
#        print(type(END))
#        input ("Press Enter")
        self.T.insert(END, "Just a text Widget\nin two lines\n")
        self.T.insert('end', "Just a text Widget\nin two lines\n")
        self.T.focus_set()
```

Comment: Use the string "end" instead of `END` or `tk.END`. There's no reason to use the constant.

Comment: I think I have found some of my answer.  I changed "END" to "tk.END" and I added the pack statement as follows.self.T.pack()

Comment: Hello Bryan. Thanks for the clue on the "tk.END".  The constant END seams to be what many programmers users and it is defined in the module.  So I think that is reason to do so.  I am groping in the dark here.

Comment: there's nothing special going on here. tkinter provides constants such as `END` that are nothing more than the string `"end"`. If you do `import tkinter`, then it's `tkinter.END`. if you do `from tkinter import *` then it's just `END`. This is simply how all python importing works.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access `END` which is available when you do `from tkinter import *`, you'd have to access it as `tk.END` when you do `import tkinter as tk`. Or, you can simply use `'end'`. Another solution would be `from tkinter.constants import END`.

Comment: I would say to always use the quoted method. This will prevent problems no mater how you are importing.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to prefix the END constant as tk.END and that cleared on error.

I found I had to add a PACK statement after the Text window insert statement.  The page code becomes:

```
class StartPage(tk.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    label = tk.Label(self, text="Blast it!", font=XLARGE_FONT)
    label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

    label_2 = tk.Label(self, text="Input Text Here", font=LARGE_FONT)
    label_2.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

    self.T = tk.Text(self, height=40, width=60, bd=10)        
    self.T.insert(tk.END, "Just a text Widget\nin two lines\n")
    self.T.focus_set()
    self.T.pack()
```

Comment: Please do not answer your own question when one was given that is accurate. You should delete this post and accept @mentalita as the correct answer. Also I do not think you need focus_set() here. It serves no useful purpose that I can see in your code.

Answer (score 0):

use "end" instead of END

```
from tkinter import *
 self.T.insert("end", "Just a text Widget\nin two lines\n")
```